# Side-by-side comparison of df's with duplicates_dropped

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, outer-join

I have the following very basic df's:

df1:

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

df2:

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   7
2   3   6
```

I would like to have a comparison of them where the result is showing only the rows/columns where there are differences but I also need to know what the original df's looked like in order to trace the reason for the differences. Expected output should be:

```
 A_df1 B_df1 A_df2 B_df2
1     2     5     2     7
```

I have always used the standard codes below when performing such differences-comparisons/outer joins:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Using the concat and drop_duplicates combo is great, however, it will not allow me to have a side by side view of where the differences are coming from - it instead only shows me the differences and I need to trace them one by one.

I have tried to add prefixes to the columns which makes sense below:

```
df1_with_suffix = df1.add_suffix('_df1')
df2_with_suffix = df2.add_suffix('_df2')
```

However, I cannot understand why when I perform the concat/drop_duplicates I continue to get all the data - i.e. duplicates are not dropping?

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, you can add [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to have a *side-by-side* comparison :

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["df1", "df2"])
           .drop_duplicates(keep=False).unstack(0).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
           .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map("{0[0]}_{0[1]}".format), axis=1)))
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   A_df1  B_df1  A_df2  B_df2
1      2      5      2      7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try   :

```
details = {
    'a' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Age_a' : [23, 21, 22, 21]}

df = pd.DataFrame(details)
  
details_2 = {'a' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Age_b' : [23, 21, 100, 21]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(details_2)
df_all = pd.merge(df, df2[['a', 'Age_b']], on = ['a'], how='left')
df_all = df_all.loc[(df_all['Age_a'] - df_all['Age_b']) != 0 ]


 #   a  Age_a   Age_b
 #   2  3   22  100
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question correctly. First of all, I want to say that `concat` & `drop_duplicates` are not suitable code for what you are trying to do.

problem of your code : Duplicates in the same data frame (ex. df1) are also removed.

use following code :

```
cond1 = ~df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1)
pd.concat([df1.add_suffix('_df1')[cond1], df2.add_suffix('_df2')[cond1]], axis=1)
```

output:

```
      A_df1 B_df1 A_df2 B_df2
1     2     5     2     7
```

And if there's anything else you want, please explain in more detail and I'll help.

Comment: Not really following why using concat and drop_duplicates is not suitable though? I want all duplicates (in both df's) to not reflect.

Comment: As written in the answer, if there is the same data in df1, it is deleted.

Comment: But that is correct - I want the duplicate rows to be deleted. I only want to see the rows where there is a difference.

Comment: if 1st and 2nd rows of df1 are same and  1st and 2nd rows of df2 are same, df1 and df2 are different but all are deleted.

Comment: Would the correct thing here not be to say: cond1 = df1.ne(df2).all(axis=1)?

Comment: It seems to have simply concatenated the 2 df's with all rows showing. Will continue to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `df1.add_suffix('_df1')` and `df2.add_suffix('_df2')`, there are 4 columns to compare, for example, `A_df1` and `A_df2` are considered different columns, so there will be no duplicate rows.

I like your `pd.concat()` and `drop_duplicates()` combo, it's great!
But you could continue by sorting the index, then concatenating the odd rows with the even rows side by side, for example

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,7,6]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).sort_index()
output = pd.concat([df.add_suffix('_df1').iloc[::2], df.add_suffix('_df2').iloc[1::2]], axis=1)
print(output)
```

Output

```
   A_df1  B_df1  A_df2  B_df2
1      2      5      2      7
```

Note that the row index `1` is preserved, so you can go back to `df1` and `df2` to look for the difference in that index.